# Where to start , secure an AWS Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: webserver, server, ubuntu, websites, amazon

Ok so this is probably a basic question but I would like to expand my knowledge.

I have created an AWS Ubuntu EC2 server. I am running software on the server that provides 2 services , firstly a website that will be available to the Internet. Secondly a password protected user environment where suppliers can view things like invoices and create new users ect.

So what I am basically asking is where do I even start to secure this environment. What would be the best steps to secure the server. It runs Nginx, Python and php .

Any input would be highly appreciated, I have a basic understanding of security having studied security at honors in uni, but that was a while ago and theoretical knowledge is useless compared to practical knowledge which I lack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some starting points which are by no means an exhaustive list (I will edit the post as people comment; and credit them too):

- [Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) - only allow access to ports that explicitly require it (in your case probably only SSH and HTTP/S). I've linked to UFW because it's easy.
- [Disable root login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27559/how-do-i-disable-remote-ssh-login-as-root-from-a-server) - furthermore consider limiting to a particular set of users - you will need to sudo (info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) and [here](https://xkcd.com/149/)) and ensure that passwords are required (see `man visudo`)
- [SSH PubKey Authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) - instead of logging in with a password, the SSH server has a list of public keys that are authorised for access.
- Make sure that you regularly upgrade software: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;`
- My preference would be to install NGINX from source as the repositories lag the bug (including security) fixes.
- Force HTTPS (a certificate is no more than $15 annually) with [HSTS](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_for_Apache_NGINX_and_Lighttpd.html). Do not disable HTTP entirely, but rather create a regular HTTP `server` (i.e. port 80) block in NGINX and use `return 301 https://yourdomain.tld;`. Do not include either of the `$uri` or `$request_path` variables as these can be manipulated over HTTP.

Comment: Fantastic, Tahnks. I have setup the firewall currently for SSH , HTTP and HTTPS because I am still setting up HTTPS (will disable HTTP once HTTPS is up and running). I will look at root login and SSH is already set up with AWS and I have the keys for myself. The SSH Auth will only be for direct login onto the OS correct? @arran-schlosberg

Comment: You shouldn't disable HTTP entirely; just redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with NGINX's `return 301 https://yourdomain.tld;`. I will update the post to reflect this.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean regarding direct login onto the OS. As against?

Comment: I have not used SSH for very much, when I created the EC2 instance on AWS it created the SSH keys and this is what I use with putty to access the Instance. How else would you use SSH?

Comment: That is the primary use of SSH; to access a Secure SHell (you can think of a shell as a command line). I haven't used Putty very much, but from memory it requires keys in a particular format and you may have to modify the AWS-created ones. You should really be generating your own private key rather than having it produced by a 3rd party as this undermines the security of PubKeyAuthentication.

Comment: Thanks yes you have to convert the keys to work with putty , but putty gen cando this for you. Then I have to ask monitoring, how would you monitor the server to identify if someone has accessed when they shouldn't? I mean do you have to wait for the server to crash, or see that files have been changed?

Comment: Perhaps that's a topic for a new question :) Probably beyond the scope of "where to start", and it would benefit others who are interested in the answer if it were separated.

Comment: Great , fully agree. I will look at what we have discussed and ask this on a new question . Will give it a bit more time before I mark this question as answered . See if anyone else has more to add. Thanks for your input.